# Python IDLE will not open

Tags: python, startup, python-idle

After fumbling with some keys on my keyboard while trying to get a script to run by clicking on Run in python IDLE I must of did something, because now python will not open. It opens from the command prompt fine, but the normal way it will not open whatsoever. I tried repairing and reinstalling. Still no luck. I am on Windows 7 machines 64bit, using the 32bit version of python 2.7. No idea what it could be but I did find something on google that mentioned something about keybindings or something? Please help!

[image: issue]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try executing `C:\path\to\python.exe -m idlelib.idle` in command prompt, is there any error message?

Comment: Yes, here's a pretty picture showing you what was outputted:http://i14.photobucket.com/albums/a331/madhatterdisease/pythonerror.jpg

Comment: @tSs: do you have a directory named `random` or a file named `random.py` somewhere?

Comment: Yes, and deleting it has allowed me to start up python normally again. Thank you sir, you truly are a wizard.